# How to parse JSON with escaped doublequotes, using node.js?

Tags: node.js, json, parsing, escaping, double-quotes

Here is an example of some JSON I am working with:

```
{"name":"John","attributes":"{\"key\":\"value\"}"}
```

Here it is again, in a more readable format:

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "attributes": "{\"key\":\"value\"}"
}
```

Notice above that the doublequotes surrounding **key** and **value** are escaped.  That's necessary, and is valid JSON (checked at jsonlint.com).

I am trying to get the value of "name", but the escaped doublequotes are causing an error.

What am I doing wrong in my node.js code?

```
var theString = '{"name":"John","attributes":"{\"key\":\"value\"}"}';
var theJSON = JSON.parse(theString);
var theName = theJSON.name;
console.log("name = " + theName);
```

Below is the output.  The error occurs on the 2nd line of my code, where I "JSON.parse()" the string.  JSON.parse seems to be removing the backslashes, turning valid JSON into invalid JSON.

```
undefined:1
{"name":"John","attributes":"{"key":"value"}"}
                               ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token k in JSON at position 31
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since that part of the data is JSON-within-JSON, you'd parse the JSON, then parse the JSON on the `attributes` property:

```
const obj = JSON.parse(json);
obj.attributes = JSON.parse(obj.attributes);
```

Live Example:

```js
const json = document.getElementById("json").textContent;

const obj = JSON.parse(json);
obj.attributes = JSON.parse(obj.attributes);
console.log(obj);
```

```html
<pre id="json">{
    "name": "John",
    "attributes": "{\"key\":\"value\"}"
}</pre>
```

Comment: T.J., can you give an example that doesn't use document.getElementById("json").textContent ?  I am calling a REST API, and get a string back.  That's what I have to work with.

Comment: @metrangia - `json` in that example is a string, just as though you'd gotten it from a rest API. (That's actually why I did it the way I did, so I wouldn't have to create the JSON using escaped backslashes in string literals and such.)